# Write text near square css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created simple square like this

```
#square_gray {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: gray;
}
```

near it I want to write something, I want to get something like this:

[image]

so I try:

```
<div class="row">

       <span id="square_gray"> <div class="col-md-6">Production Locations</div></span>
        <div class="col-md-6">Global Service Office</div>
</div>
```

But it just don't display square.. what am I  doing wrong?

Comment: You are using which bootstrap ?

Comment: 3.3.7 @NanditaAroraSharma

Comment: Ok updated answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<span>`element is an inline element, not a block one. This means you can't set the width and height property.

You can set your element to `display: inline-block` and put it inside your div :

```
<div class="col-md-6"><span id="square_gray"></span>Production Locations</div>
```

Rather than :

```
<span id="square_gray"> <div class="col-md-6">Production Locations</div></span>
```

You could also :

- Use the unicode black square character ■
- Put the black square unicode character between `<span id="square_grey">■</span><div class="col-md-6">Production Locations</div>`
- Change you #square_grey style to set the color of the font `color: gray;`

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML like shown below.Also add style `display: inline-block` tothe span, else it wont take space without text in it.

```css
 
#square_gray {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-6" style="display: flex;">
       <span id="square_gray" style="display: inline-block;"> 
       </span>
       Production Locations
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">Global Service Office</div>
</div>
```